# Best way to install gutters on roof with no vertical facia or eaves

Tags: waterproofing, roofing, gutters

Hopefully the photo will illustrate the problem. I have a roof that only has a sort of moulding that transitions from roofing to the walls. Since there is only about 3/4" of vertical material to anchor gutters clips, are there any specialty hardware or other techniques to hang gutters along this facia.

[image: Photo of roof facia]
[image: closeup]

Comment: Are you certain you want/need gutters?  Aside from fixing possible foundation drainage issues, they're usually more trouble than worth.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Good point. There are a few spots that I'm pretty sure gutters are the only way to fix the issue (like over a garage door) but I'll keep that in mind for some other places that may not be totally necessary

Answer (score 7):

This would be a situation where you'll have to use gutter straps (usually in T or K style):
[image]

<sub>Image credit to acehardware.com</sub>

They install on the roof decking - make sure to follow the manufacturer's instructions, as  you'll be penetrating the singles.

[image]

<sub>Image credit to www.heritagehillweb.org</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Usually this is prepared at the time of roof install, but with care, may be retrofitted, using these brackets.[image: roof bracket]